# Estimation of a explicit Riemann-integral

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, substitution, estimation, beta-function

I have a explicit integral of the form,
$$ \int_s^t((r-s)^{-a}+(r-s)^{b-a})(t-r)^{a + b -1} d r $$,

Where $0 \leq s < t \leq T$, $b \in (\frac{1}{2},1)$ and $1-b < a <b $.

I have to Show that this integral is smaller or equal than $(t-s)^{C_1 \times b } + (t-s)^{C_2 \times  b }$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are some real numbers. Someone sad that i have to substitute and use the beta-function, but i have no idea how. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

We want to  arrive at something like the beta function $B$ defined as :

$$
B(x,y)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} \operatorname d t
$$
With substitution $x=\frac{r-s}{t-s}$ we get
$$
x=\frac{r-s}{t-s} \iff r = x(t-s)+s \iff \operatorname d r = (t-s) \operatorname d x 
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{split}
I&=\int_s ^ t (r-s)^{-a}\left(1+ (r-s)^{-b} \right)(t-r)^{a+b-1} \operatorname d r \\
&=(t-s)^{b} \left[ \int_0^1 x^{-a}  (1-x)^{a+b-1}\operatorname d x +  \int_0^1 x^{-a-b} (t-s)^{-b} (1-x)^{a+b-1}\operatorname d x \right]\\
&=(t-s)^b \int_0^1 x^{-a}  (1-x)^{a+b-1}\operatorname d x  + \int_0^1 x^{-(a+b)}(1-x)^{a+b-1} \operatorname d x \\
&= (t-s)^{b} \cdot B(1-a,a+b)  + B(1-a-b,a+b)
\end{split}
$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Hey, that is perfekt. But how do know what subsitution you have to Do? Another question to the beta-function.  Are the values of the beta-function always finite and positive?

Comment: Well, the Beta function $B(x,y)$ is defined for $x,y>0$ and is positive because that we are integrating a positive function, since $t$ and $(1-t)$ are non negative. For the substitution: I made two substitutions: first $u=r-s$ and then $x = \frac{u}{t-s}$. After that, I realized that only was necessary one single substitution.

Comment: Well, I also did the First Substitution but did not come further. Thank you very much.